# How to send data to ActivityRecognition Intent Service without replacing its activity data?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-intentservice, activity-recognition, user-activity

I am working on user activity tracking application.

I have used the Activity Recognition API to track the user activity.

I have set the Intent service to be called to get the user activity at specified interval for example every 20 seconds.

Below is my **Activity recognition intent service class :**

```
/**
 * Called when a new activity detection update is available.
 */
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {   
   // mPId = intent.getStringExtra("PID");
```

> --- When I send some data by put extra along with pending intent here i am not getting the user activity intent data. The User activity intent data is replaced by my data

```
    // If the intent contains an result data
    if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        // Get the update
        ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult
                .extractResult(intent);

        // Log the update
        saveActivityRecognitionResult(result);
    }
}
```

The above code working fine If I have not passed any own data.

I want to send some data along with this intent. I set that data along with pending intent. But If I set the data I am received only that data not the user activity intent data.

I don't want to to use the shared preference to store and fetch it inside of intent service wont work out.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Post the code that you use to "set your own data in the Intent"

Answer (score 0):

I'd not pass this intent further but take data in your `onHandleIntent` and add it to other intent.

I assume you're trying to pass this intent to some service which stores activity data in sqlite or something... there's a catch.

Don't use `IntentService`, because before or during it's doing its job phone may go asleep if you will not acquire `WakeLock`. Get familiar with [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) to deal with it.

The other solution is to just use `BroadcastReceiver` as it's guaranteed phone will not go asleep.